# How do I create a timer for my game?

Tags: java, android

I am building a game in Android 2.2 but I'm struggling to be able to show a timer on screen during play and saving the time to a Leaderboard upon Game Over.

I have a game loop and I've extended the SurfaceView to show my graphics.

I don't think my game `loop` runs accurately every millisecond so I'm finding it difficult to grab the time.

I want to get to having a stored variable called `time` storing the milliseconds and a method called `getFormattedTime()` which would get the time as `Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds`

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you heard of [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) class in Java ?

Comment: Thanks! I used a Timer and TimerTask to resolve my issue in the end! (Post your comment as an answer and I'll give you the tick :))

Comment: i have post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class named [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) in Java. It allows to  perform the activity on certain period of interval. You can use this class to create a timer for your game application.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 by calling `System.currentTimeMillis()`.
You can then take a difference between a stored value and a new currenTimeMillis to determine the amount of milliseconds that have passed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the above if not getting as you wished you can try this but its rounding around

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int min= c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
String time=min+":"+seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this myself by creating a `Timer` and `TimerTask` and using these as a separate loop for timekeeping purposes. Thanks to all for your help anyway.